# Oracle:query optimization

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I have two tables `tab1` and `tab2`.`tab1` has 108000 rows and `tab2` has 1200000 rows.

 Here is sample data
`tab1`

```
+-----------------------------------------------------+
|       Low        |         high        | Region_id  |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
|5544220000000000  |   5544225599999999  |     1      |
|5544225500000000  |   5544229999999999  |     2      |
|5511111100000000  |   5511111199999999  |     3      |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

`tab2`

```
+------------------+
|       pan        |
+-------------------
|5544221111111111  |
|5544225524511244  |
|5511111111254577  |
+------------------+
```

So I run a query like this

```
select t2.pan, t1.region_id from tab2 t2
 join tab1 t1 on t2.pan between t1.low and t1.high;
```

What I'm trying to do is finding in which range does `tab2.pan` exist and retrieving it's `region_id`: Ranges are unique, Meanning that low and high pairs are distinct.
I tried adding indexes, running in parallel but the query is running very slow(about 3 hours). 
Can anyone suggest something to fasten the query, it can be adding some kind of indexes, or changing data structure or anything else.
I'm running the query against Oracle 11gR2. 
**UPDATE**

 From the comments i tested several things
Adding index like (high, low) and adding index (pan) and (high, low, region), Both ways there goes index full scan, i also tried index on(low,high) and index on pan, this way goes index range scan on tab1 and index full scan on tab2, but anyways it seems extremely slow.

Comment: Indexes, primary keys, foreign keys?

Comment: @jarlh I have tried adding indexes both in tab1.high and tab1.low but there goes index full scan and the query works very slow. There is no primary key in both tab1 and tab2.

Comment: I though about a multi-columns index on (low, high). I think that this way the engine will perform an index range scan on tab1.

Comment: Presumably there are other columns than just the ones you've mentioned in the tables? Assuming that's true, have you tried an index on T1 of (low, high, region) and on T2 of (pan)?

Comment: @NeriaNachum I havent tried that, i'll try it straight away

Comment: @Boneist I'll try your suggestion too, and yes there are more columns in the tables that are mentioned here.

Comment: Guys I've added an update to the post from testing your suggestions, pleas look at it.

Comment: What data types are you using for `low` and `high`?

Comment: @MihaiOvidiuDrăgoi they are of ``varchar2(16)``

Comment: Changing to a numeric data type might have significant impact on performance (sample data is numeric). Please try that too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have no overlaps and each value in `tab1` matches exactly one row in `tab2`, then I think the best approach is a correlated subquery with the right indexes:

```
select t.*, t2.region_id
from (select t1.*,
             (select max(t2.low)
              from tab2 t2
              where t2.low <= t.pan
             ) as t2low
      from tab1 t1
     ) t join
     tab2 t2
     on t.t2low = t2.low;
```

The index that you want is `tab2(low, region)`.  This index should be used very efficiently for the subquery to get the closest `low` value.  The join should then be quite fast as well.

Does this help your performance?

EDIT:

I should note that in the above query, you can test for the `high` value in the outer join.  This should be fine if the the `low` values are unique, because the join on `low` will be really fast.  So:

```
select t.*,
       (case when t.pan <= t2.high then t2.region_id end) as region_id
from (select t1.*,
             (select max(t2.low)
              from tab2 t2
              where t2.low <= t.pan
             ) as t2low
      from tab1 t1
     ) t join
     tab2 t2
     on t.t2low = t2.low;
```

Comment: I'll write back a bit later as soon as i end up with testing.

Comment: Sir that seems to be working. I'll accept this as an answer as soon as I try it on production, unluckily it is not possible today.